# This function must be called from a UI thread

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp

Using the following Microsoft web page as a reference..
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/store-developer-package-update

I am trying to write code to update a test application I have uploaded to the Microsoft Store. Uploaded to the store is a simple dialog and a few updates (changed background color) written in C# Windows Forms using a UWP wrapper in the form of a Windows Application Packaging Project.

The dialog has a couple of buttons, one of which calls the following cut/paste methods from the above webpage..

```
private async void InstallUpdatesAsync()
{
    StoreContext updateManager = StoreContext.GetDefault();
    IReadOnlyList<StorePackageUpdate> updates = await updateManager.GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync();

    // Save app state here

    IAsyncOperationWithProgress<StorePackageUpdateResult, StorePackageUpdateStatus> installOperation =
        updateManager.RequestDownloadAndInstallStorePackageUpdatesAsync(updates);

    StorePackageUpdateResult result = await installOperation.AsTask();

    // Under normal circumstances, app will terminate here

    // Handle error cases here using StorePackageUpdateResult from above
}
```

I am getting the error..

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been
> thrown by the target of an invocation.'
>
> Inner Exception Exception: Invalid window handle.
>
> This function must be called from a UI thread

I don't understand this as I am calling it from a button from a dialog box. I have seen various comments elsewhere that the commands have to be called from a UI thread, but I cannot find out how.

Any help much appreciated.

EDIT:

```
private void installButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rtb.SelectionColor = CommandColor;
    rtb.AppendText("Installing updates\n\n");

    


    InstallUpdatesAsync();

}
```

Comment: hrm, is that all your code in that particular method?

Comment: also show how you are calling InstallUpdatesAsync

Comment: Are you using `ConfigureAwait(false)`? Have you got a custom `SynchronizationContext`?

Comment: Use Dispatcher, if you dont have it you can try implementing your own RunSync extension method usin SynchronizationContext.

Comment: In short the issue is not with the code you have shown, there is more to the story, otherwise marshal back to the UI thread with usual means

Comment: I have edited the question, but the program is a single dialog, three buttons and a RichTextBox for comments. Each button contains one of the check/download/install methods, but this one was the simplest to ask about. There really is no more to the story!

Comment: Don't return `async void` unless it's required (event handlers).  Return `Task` or `Task<T>`.  The button click should be marked `async` and you should do `await InstallUpdatesAsync();`  Also you should know what line of code is throwing in the stack trace.

Comment: `private async void installButton_Click(...) { [...] await InstallUpdatesAsync();}  private async Task InstallUpdatesAsync() { ... }`

Comment: @Jimi That's pretty much the same as what Zer0 said to do. Error is on line         `StorePackageUpdateResult result = await installOperation.AsTask();`

Comment: I didn't read that other comment, that's just how you write that part. Now you know that `await installOperation.AsTask();` isn't actually awaited and executes in another Thread. What is this method doing? Why do you have `.AsTask()` there? Is that a ValueTask, WindowsRuntime action... You've been asked whether you're setting `ConfigureAwait(false)` there. Are you?

Comment: @Jimi I cannot answer any of that, I just start with the MS given code example and work from there. I get compile errors when I remove the `.AsTask()` so I leave it there. I would rather handle the threading myself, but that's the example given.

Comment: @Jimi I should say too that before your changes, the error was in the line           `IAsyncOperationWithProgress<StorePackageUpdateResult, StorePackageUpdateStatus> installOperation =
                updateManager.RequestDownloadAndInstallStorePackageUpdatesAsync(updates);`

Comment: Now I see the examples you linked. Are they really using `async void` everywhere? Change the methods to a Task Type and `await` those calls.

Comment: @Jimi That is pretty much what you said before. I have tried that again and still get the same errors. Could this just be a UWP internal error?

Comment: The Windows Runtime probably uses `AsyncInfo.Run()` on the *other side*, so it returns a `TProgress` object delegate as part of the `IAsyncOperationWithProgress<TResult,TProgress>`. The `TProgress` delegate is supposed to resume to the captured context, so should the `Completed` result. Take the `Progress` delegate of `installOperation` (as a Lambda, see the `DownloadUpdatesAsync()` method in the example you linked) and perform any updates from there. I'm not sure how `async void` behaves in this context (probably not good in WinForms). You'll have to make some tests and find out.

Answer (score 0):

I did not work in UWP, but some controls are inside the UI thread and because the function that is running is multiple threads, it is not allowed to run. I put a code below but I do not know if it works or not.

```
private async void installButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   rtb.SelectionColor = CommandColor;
   rtb.AppendText("Installing updates\n\n");
    
  
   await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () => {
         InstallUpdatesAsync()
   });
}
```

Comment: meysam asadi, thanks for you answer, but still same errors.

Comment: see this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync?view=winrt-19041

Comment: I put another line of code, the test trap is not without grace.

Comment: `Application does not contain a definition for Current`

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your own helper class and use it's `RunSync` extension method, it will be your universal solution, eliminating requirement to adapt different Dispatcher implementations from different platforms.

```
    public static class AsyncHelpers
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Execute's an async Task<T> method which has a void return value synchronously
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="task">Task<T> method to execute</param>
        public static void RunSync(Func<Task> task)
        {
            var oldContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            var synch = new ExclusiveSynchronizationContext();
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(synch);
            synch.Post(async _ =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await task();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    synch.InnerException = e;
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    synch.EndMessageLoop();
                }
            }, null);
            synch.BeginMessageLoop();

            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(oldContext);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Execute's an async Task<T> method which has a T return type synchronously
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Return Type</typeparam>
        /// <param name="task">Task<T> method to execute</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static T RunSync<T>(Func<Task<T>> task)
        {
            var oldContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            var synch = new ExclusiveSynchronizationContext();
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(synch);
            T ret = default;
            synch.Post(async _ =>
            {
                try
                {
                    ret = await task();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    synch.InnerException = e;
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    synch.EndMessageLoop();
                }
            }, null);
            synch.BeginMessageLoop();
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(oldContext);
            return ret;
        }

        private class ExclusiveSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
        {
            private readonly Queue<Tuple<SendOrPostCallback, object>> _Items =
                new Queue<Tuple<SendOrPostCallback, object>>();

            private readonly AutoResetEvent _WorkItemsWaiting = new AutoResetEvent(false);

            private bool _Done;

            public Exception InnerException { get; set; }

            public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("We cannot send to our same thread");
            }

            public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
            {
                lock (_Items)
                {
                    _Items.Enqueue(Tuple.Create(d, state));
                }

                _WorkItemsWaiting.Set();
            }

            public void EndMessageLoop()
            {
                Post(_ => _Done = true, null);
            }

            public void BeginMessageLoop()
            {
                while (!_Done)
                {
                    Tuple<SendOrPostCallback, object> task = null;
                    lock (_Items)
                    {
                        if (_Items.Count > 0) task = _Items.Dequeue();
                    }

                    if (task != null)
                    {
                        task.Item1(task.Item2);
                        if (InnerException != null) // the method threw an exeption
                            throw new AggregateException("AsyncHelpers.Run method threw an exception.", InnerException);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _WorkItemsWaiting.WaitOne();
                    }
                }
            }

            public override SynchronizationContext CreateCopy()
            {
                return this;
            }
        }
    }
```